# Changing the base path of an assembly from the bin directory to a different directory

Tags: c#, .net

I have a **Test.cs** file in **C:\** This test file reads from an input file and writes the same to an output file.
Test.cs

```
public class Test
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader("in.txt");
        string input = reader.ReadLine();
        var writer = new StreamWriter("out.txt");
        writer.WriteLine(input);
        return 0;
     }
 }
```

Here it should be noted that the code only uses the **filename** and **not the full file path**, which means the file is expected to be in the directory where the program is running. And I have created the in.txt in C:\

Now, there is a c# code called **Runner.cs** in a solution in **C:\Project\Runner.cs**, that **dynamically compiles** the **Test.cs** code and runs it using reflection. Now, when the Test.cs runs, it expects the in.txt file to be in **C:\Project\bin\Debug\in.txt** , but it is actually present in **C:\in.txt**

So, my question is, is there a way to make the code to get the file from C:\in.txt and not from the bin directory **without changing the path of the file in the Test.cs** code file.

**Edit:** It is my bad that I forgot to mention why I am in need of this requirement.

The Test.cs file comes from over the wire. And I felt it will not be a good choice to edit this file and set the file path accordingly. I want to compile it and run it as it is.

I hope I am clear. If not, please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Why not to use full path ?? What is the issue if file is in bin directory ??

Comment: You could try to set the [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does Runner.cs executes Test in its own process or does Runner do a Process.Execute?

Comment: @GrantWinney: Sorry, my bad. I have updated the post to specify why I need it this way.

Comment: @rene: Runner uses the Type.Invoke method to run the Test.cs, so, within its own process.

Comment: Why don't you pass input and output filename as parameters to main? That way you don't need to edit the code you got, the author just needs to take this into account.

Comment: @Balasubramanian May be another option : Use System.IO.File.Move(string newPath) static File Method, or same method overloaded with a new FileName option or System.IO.Copy(path) Methods according to your project needs.. NOTE : About Compiler options..There should be a settable "Output" property which can developer decide where compiler compile the source by set this property..

Comment: @Balasubramanian As an example : var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(); var compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit(); var parameter = new CompilerParameters(); var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"\YourFolder"; var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameter, compileUnit);
  if (path != null) results.PathToAssembly = path;
 
  results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));    Please Note to "path" variable : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory always the best universal option in all projects (MVC, SL, winforms etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is as simple as you show in your code switching the CurrentDirectory works for this example:

```
var mainMembers = new CSharpCodeProvider()
    .CreateCompiler()
    .CompileAssemblyFromSource(
        new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true }
        , @"
        using System; 
        using System.IO;
        public class M {
            public static int Main() { 
                Console.WriteLine(""CurDir = ""+ Environment.CurrentDirectory); 
                var reader = new StreamReader(""in.txt"");
                string input = reader.ReadLine();
                var writer = new StreamWriter(""out.txt"");
                writer.WriteLine(input);
                return 0;
            }
        }")
     .CompiledAssembly
     .GetType("M")
     .GetMember("Main");
 // inspect
 Environment.CurrentDirectory.Dump("current");
 // keep 
 var oldcd = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
 // switch
 Environment.CurrentDirectory = "c:\\temp";
 // invoke external code
 ((MethodInfo) mainMembers[0]).Invoke(null,null);
 // restore
 Environment.CurrentDirectory = oldcd;
```

In a multi threaded scenario this becomes unreliable.

Comment: As is the case, the code has to work in a multi-threaded environment where in, there can be multiple such code files coming in through the wire and for each such code, a thread will be started to process it. So, any suggestions on that??